# Attribute table multiple selections from external data file

Tags: attribute-table, attribute-joins, select-by-attribute

I have a county parcels attribute file in which I can select a row entry and have it highlighted on the shapefile (standard behavior). I also have a separate file (excel or dBase) with entries for certain properties of interest (based on property id).  In v3.16, Using data from the second file, is there a way to select multiple entries in the attrib file programmatically and have them highlighted all at the same time?

Comment: Please update your question to include the software/version you are using.

Comment: Are you using version 3.16 of QGIS or of another GIS product?